# Multiple regexes with awk

Tags: regex, linux, awk

I have a file. I have to apply multiple regexes one by one in `Linux` with `AWK` command.
Here is my example File:

```
Start connection Test from LAN end
Link are Test is complete available
Test    
Start connection from LAN 
Test is complete
end
Test1 is complete
Test2 is complete
Link are available
Link are Test is complete available
Test1
```

I want to apply 3 rules:

1. dont see between `Start` and `end`
2. dont see between `Link` and `available`
3. see `Test`

I have used three AWK 
`awk '/Start/ {f=1} !f; /end/ {f=0}'` , `awk '/Link/ {f=1} !f; /available/ {f=0}'` and `awk '/Test/{f=1}f;/complete/{f=0}'`
Now i want to combine all together in one `AWK`.

How can i do that?

Answer (score 5):

Just use different dummy variables:

```
awk '/Start/ {f=1} /Link/ {g=1} /Test/ {h=1} !f && !g && h; /end/ {f=0} /available/ {g=0} /complete/ {h=0}'
```

Answer (score 1):

This single awk should work:

```
awk '{
   gsub(/Start.*end/, "");
   gsub(/Link.*available/, "");
   split($0, a, "\n");
   for (i=0; i<length(a); i++)
      if (index(a[i], "Test"))
         print a[i]
}' RS= file
```